# Error when importing igraph: ImportError:cannot import name community_to_membership

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, igraph

I'm not sure if this has been answered already, but I couldn't find anything related to my error, so I figured I would post a question.

I'm running on Linux and I've downloaded the igraph package using `pip install python-igraph` and made sure it is the python-igraph-0.7.1 package provided by Tamas Nepusz.

When I try to do `import igraph`, I get the following errors:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lashen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
  File "/home/lashen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/igraph/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from igraph.cut import *
  File "/home/lashen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/cut.py", line 5, in <module>
    from igraph.clustering import VertexClustering
  File "/home/lashen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/igraph/clustering.py", line 32, in <module>
    from igraph import community_to_membership
ImportError: cannot import name community_to_membership
```

I'm not sure how to fix this import error. Did I install igraph incorrectly?? Seems like I got the right package ...

```
~$ pip show python-igraph
Name: python-igraph
Version: 0.7.1.post6
Summary: High performance graph data structures and algorithms
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph
Author: Tamas Nepusz
Author-email: tamas@cs.rhul.ac.uk
License: GNU General Public License (GPL)
Location: /home/lashen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

I have tried importing individual submodules of igraph, but to no avail. All submodule imports (e.g. `import igraph.cut`, `import igraph._igraph`) all result in the same error.

Why is this import error appearing? Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: `python-igraph` are the python *bindings* to the igraph core (which is written in C or C++, IIRC). You need to install `libigraph` first (sudo apt-get install libigraph-dev), then `pip install python-igraph`.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't have permission to run `sudo` on my Linux environment. Is there another way to install `libigraph`? Thanks!

Comment: Nvm, my admin just kindly agreed to install libigraph! Will let you know if the import error goes away.

Comment: My admin installed `libigraph0-dev`, and I uninstalled python-igraph and re-installed with `pip install --user python-igraph`, but I still see the same import error :(

Comment: Okay, I just tried with python3 instead (e.g. `pip3 install --user python-igraph`) and `import igraph` works now in python3!! Thanks so much, Paul! :)

Comment: I have no idea why using pip3 should have done the job when pip (which should default to pip3 in a python3 environment) failed. Glad it worked out, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `sudo apt-get install libigraph0-dev` first and then you can install igraph via `pip install python-igraph --user`